# Load and run .exe file or CompilerResults to memory?

Tags: c#, process

Is it possible to load `CSC CompilerResults` into memory instead making `.exe` file of it?

My code for compilation and execution look like this (shorten version):

```
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        var parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = true,
            OutputAssembly = exeName,
            GenerateInMemory = false,
            TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
        };

        var compiler = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
        private Process process = new Process();

        // set parameters of process like filename, use shell execute etc

        process.Start();

        // do stuff with it like StandardInput.Writeline or StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

        process.WaitForExit();

        // deleting executed .exe file:

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(process.StartInfo.FileName);
        file.Delete();
```

My question is it any easy way to load compiled code to memory and execute it from memory instead of making `.exe` file, start it as `Process` and then deleting that `.exe`?

Comment: You can compile the results to memory, I believe... but I don't *think* you can launch a process just based on memory. If you are in a situation where a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software) makes sense, that's one option to consider.

Comment: I editet my question. I want to Load `exe` or `CompilerResults` to memory and do stuff with it like `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` stuff. Is it possible in easy way like `Process` class?

Comment: Again, no, I don't believe you can run a process without a file in the file system. That's not a matter of the `Process` class not supporting it - that's an operating system restriction, as far as I'm aware.